# jQuery .toggle effect pushing down button

Tags: jquery, forms, button, toggle

What happens when I click on the button? Instead to remain in place, button moves down and 
return to.. Here is a HTML, CSS and jQuery code... the idea is when i click the button, search form moves left. When I click the button again, search form moves back.

HTML

```
<form action="" class="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="input" />
        <input type="button" value="click me"/>
</form>
```

CSS

```
input[type="text"]
{
    display: none;
    width: 254px;
    height: 63px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: SourceSansPro, sans-serif;
    color: gray;
}
input[type="button"]
{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: -10px;
    border: none;
    width: 63px;
    height: 63px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $('input[type=button]').click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'right' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 700;

    $('input[type=text]').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GagK9/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggle()` wraps the element it was used on with `div.ui-effects-wrapper`.

You could add `display:inline-block` to this generated `div` to avoid moving `button` to the bottom.

In your particular case you can add `id` to the form (i use `myForm`) and add following css rule (for isolating this `ui-effects-wrapper` and don't touching another ones on the page):

```
#myForm .ui-effects-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

## Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/GagK9/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `position : fixed;`
in the css of `input [type=text]`, then it will remain same at that place.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the `button` element with Firebug, you'll see that when the effect is changing, the `input` element is turned into a `div` element. That's why the button is moving down, because the `div` fills the whole width.

You can add:

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
    float:left !important;
}
```

to your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/GagK9/7/

Comment: This is an other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper around the `input` element, and animate that instead:

```
<form action="" class="search">
   <div id="textinput"><input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="input" /></div>
    <input type="button" value="click me"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zdFU9/